# Slow video stream with imdecode opencv using python

Tags: python, opencv, python-2.7

I'm connecting to a IP-camera for object detection with OpenCV.The problem is that the videostream is superslow. When i comment this bit "rects = detect(gray, cascade)" the videostream is fluent.

I read that it has to do with imdecode and converting the frames to gray per frame but I cant find a solution, how can I fix this problem?

```
bytes=""
while True:
    '''authenticated connection to IP cam'''
    bytes+=stream.read(16384)
    a = bytes.find('\xff\xd8')
    b = bytes.find('\xff\xd9')
    if a!=-1 and b!=-1:
        jpg = bytes[a:b+2]
        bytes= bytes[b+2:]
        i = cv2.imdecode(np.fromstring(jpg, dtype=np.uint8),cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR)

        '''Convert frames to gray to be able to detect objects'''
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(i, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        gray = cv2.equalizeHist(gray)

        '''Detect and draw whatever you specified in haarcascades'''
        rects = detect(gray, cascade)
        vis = i.copy()
        draw_rects(vis, rects, (0, 255, 0))

        '''Display the videostream'''
        cv2.imshow('authenticated cam',vis)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) ==27:
            exit(0)
```

Comment: hey, if you want grayscale use: `cv2.imdecode(np.fromstring(jpg, dtype=np.uint8),cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)` and skip the conversion later

Comment: @berak tried it. but still slow...

Comment: actually the cascade detection will be the most expensive part. theres a scale factor in there, that you can increase for speed(like from 1.05 to 1.2) or pyrdown once before, to resize it to half ( 4 x speed)